# Texmaker autocomplete LateX citations in chapters directory

Tags: citing, texmaker

I am trying to obtain autocompletion for citations for each chapter of my thesis which are all referenced in a master document containing the following:

```
\documentclass[%
    twoside, openright, titlepage, numbers=noenddot,%
    cleardoublepage=empty,%
    abstractoff,%
    BCOR=5.5mm, paper=a5, fontsize=10pt,% A5 soft cover
    %BCOR=5.5mm, paper=17cm:24cm, fontsize=10pt,% 17 cm x 24 cm
    %BCOR=5mm, paper=15.59cm:23.39cm, fontsize=10pt,% Royal soft cover %BCOR=0mm, paper=15.24cm:22.86cm, fontsize=10pt,% US-Trade hard cover
     10 ]{scrreport}
    
    \addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
    
    \include{chapters/introduction/main}
    
    \cleardoublepage%
    \include{chapters/chapter2_theory/main}
```

[This issue has been resolved in Vim](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/37614/autocomplete-latex-citations-in-chapters-directory), but unfortunately one of the collaborators wants to open and modify it in TexMaker. The \cite{} command is not getting autocompleted for him in TexMaker for the chapters while it works on the master document. (I reproduced the error from my computer as well)
`Option` > `Configure` `TexMaker` > `Editor` > `Completion` is ticked in for all the documents.